# Linq record not in other table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

i want to know how to select those record which is not in another table.

I have a query to show all the stock in a period of time

```
    var query = (from stk in ie.stocks
                         join s in ie.staffs on stk.stk_createby equals s.stf_id
                         where stk.stk_createdate >= startDate &&
                         stk.stk_createdate <= endDate
                         select new
                         {
                             StockID = stk.stk_id,
                             RefNo = stk.stk_ref_id,
                             Weight = stk.stk_weight,
                             Grade = stk.stk_grade,
                             Remark = stk.stk_remark,
                             StaffName = s.stf_name
                         }).ToList();
```

And also i have another query to show all delivered stock.

```
                var query2 = (from ol in ie.orderLists
                              join stk in ie.stocks on ol.ol_stockid equals stk.stk_id
                              join dl in ie.deliveries on ol.ol_dlyid equals dl.dly_id
                              join s in ie.staffs on stk.stk_createby equals s.stf_id
                              where dl.dly_delivery_date >= startDate &&
                              dl.dly_delivery_date <= endDate
                              select new
                              {
                                  StockID = stk.stk_id,
                                  RefN = stk.stk_ref_id,
                                  Weight = stk.stk_weight,
                                  Grade = stk.stk_grade,
                                  Remark = stk.stk_remark,
                                  StaffName = s.stf_name
                              }).ToList();
```

So what i want is to show the remain stock which is not deliver. How to exclude all stock in query2?

Answer (score 2):

Try Except method.

ex)

```
var ret = query1.Except(query2);
```

Comment: I tried this before but it shown error, the query1 do not contain except method.

Comment: Define your data type, and give comparer to except method.

See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/bb336390(v=vs.90).aspx